# Display custom seaborn plots from a loop as grid

Tags: python, seaborn

I have a plotting function that makes a number of enhancements to the `seaborn` `jointplot` below is the simplest version.  I also run a loop to plot one column versus all others.  My question is how can I get the resulting plots to display in an arbitrary (m x n) grid?

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

iris = sns.load_dataset('iris')
other_cols=iris.drop(["sepal_length","species"],axis=1)

def plottingFunction(df,xvar,yvar):

      
    g=sns.jointplot(x=df[xvar], y=df[yvar], kind='reg')
    

[plottingFunction(iris,i,'sepal_length') for i in other_cols]
```

Comment: Seaborn's `jointplot` is a "figure level" function, which creates its own figure with 3 subplots. It doesn't support drawing on arbitrary subplots. What you're asking isn't supported (yet).

Comment: Have you tried `corner`?